# How to get webalizer to report on directories instead of files?

Tags: webalizer

I am moving an application from passing identifiers in the query string to passing them in as part of the url.  So instead of `myobj/details?id=123`, it would be `myobj/123`

I would like to be able to have comparable webalizer statistics after this.  So I want to be able to log the full url, but report on only how many hits to `myobj/*`

Is it possible to do this?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the web for information and skimming the Webalizer source code it became clear this cannot be done out of the box.  It would require changing the source code for webalizer.

The program has pretty much all the routines needed today to do custom truncation rules so customizing the software for the task at hand doesn't look problematic.  However it is not an out of the box feature.